# Laravel Error: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Symfony\Component\Routing\CompiledRoute'

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I ran these commands: `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear`. Then I got this error on whatever I want to do: running artisan command, running composer command, rendering any view that worked just fine. Can not do anything at all.

I searched for the problem and seems that this has happened because of changing the php version from 7.4 to 7.3. Yes, I have done this about 10 days ago, now I am not able to resolve it and make it work again. I use **Nginx** and tried anything suggested on the web, but can not solve the problem. I had apache and could not solve it, I removed apache completely and installed nginx. Now any other project works fine with nginx, but only this project which I ran `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` commands, has problem and displays this error on every action I want to do: `Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Symfony\Component\Routing\CompiledRoute'`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I got this same error when I was experimenting with Laravel Envoy.  I think I pulled the 7.0 version of Envoy onto of my Laravel 5.8 version app.  The way to solve it for me was to clear out the bootstrap/cache directory of the app with the command `rm -fr bootstrap/cache/*` from the root Laravel directory. Once I did that I was able to use my application normally and all the artisan commands began working.